# I keep getting nullpointer exception for jtable getrowcount() method

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, tablemodel

I am trying to create a table that can be filtered but I keep getting a null pointer exception for the getRowCount() method in my table model class.

HomePagePanel(where my table is)

```
public class homepagePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private JButton uploadEmail, viewEmail, logout, delete;
private JLabel userLog;
private JLabel tableLabel;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private EmailTableListener emailTableListener;
//private EmailTablePanel EmailPanel;
private HomePagePanelListener homepagePanelListener;
private List<Item> dc;
private Controller controller;
private JTable table;
private EmailTableModel emailModel;
private JPopupMenu popup;
private JTextField filterText;
private JLabel filterLabel;
private TableRowSorter<EmailTableModel> sorter;




public homepagePanel() {



    controller = new Controller();

    userLog = new JLabel("Logged in:");

    uploadEmail = new JButton("Upload");
    viewEmail = new JButton("View");
    delete = new JButton("Delete");
    logout = new JButton("Log Out");
    tableLabel = new JLabel("Emails stored");

    //Email stuff
    emailModel = new EmailTableModel();
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<EmailTableModel>(emailModel);
    table = new JTable(emailModel);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);

    //
    filterLabel = new JLabel("Filter Text: ", SwingConstants.TRAILING);
    filterText = new JTextField(10);
    filterLabel.setLabelFor(filterText);

    //documenet listener
    filterText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            newFilter();
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            newFilter();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            newFilter();
        }
     });






    // Adds the table to a scrollpane
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane
            .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    popup = new JPopupMenu();

    JMenuItem removeItem = new JMenuItem("Delete row");
    popup.add(removeItem);


    //adds mouse listener to show 
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                popup.show(table, e.getX(), e.getY());//shows popup

            }
        }

    });
    //removeitem actionlistener
    removeItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();

            if(emailTableListener != null){
                emailTableListener.rowDeleted(row);
                emailModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
            }
        }

    });
    // EmailPanel = new EmailTablePanel();



    layoutComponents();

    viewEmail.addActionListener(this);
    uploadEmail.addActionListener(this);
    logout.addActionListener(this);

private void newFilter(){
    RowFilter<EmailTableModel, Object> rf = null;

    try{
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText());
    }catch(java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e){
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

TableModel

```
package view;

import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import model.Item;

public class EmailTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private List<Item> dc;
private String[] colNames = {"ID", "To", "From", "Subject", "Topic", "Message Content", "Comments", "Attachments"};

public EmailTableModel(){
    //System.out.println(dc.size());
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return colNames[column];
}


public void setData(List<Item> dc){
    this.dc = dc;
}
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 8;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dc.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    Item item = dc.get(row);

    switch(column){
    case 0: 
        return item.getId();
    case 1:
        return item.getTo();
    case 2:
        return item.getFrom();
    case 3:
        return item.getSubject();
    case 4:
        return item.getTopic();
    case 5:
        return item.getMessageContent();
    case 6:
        return item.getComments();
    case 7:
        return item.getAttachments();

    }
    return null;
}

public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    Class returnValue;
    // Verifying that the column exists(index > 0 && index < number of
    // columns
    if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
        returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    } else {
        // Returns the class for the item in the column
        returnValue = Object.class;
    }
    return returnValue;
};
```

}

database class(retriving data for jtable)

```
    public void loadItems() throws SQLException {
    //connects to the database
    getConnected();
    Items.clear();//clears the linked list
    String sql = "Select Id, Reciever, Sender, Subject, topic, Email_Content, Comments, Attachments from item order by Id";//querly for select statement
    Statement selectStatement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet results = selectStatement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (results.next()) {
        int id = results.getInt("Id");
        String To = results.getString("Reciever");
        String From = results.getString("Sender");
        String Subject = results.getString("Subject");
        String topic = results.getString("topic");
        String Email_Content = results.getString("Email_Content");
        String Comments = results.getString("Comments");
        String Attachments = results.getString("Attachments");

        Item item = new Item(id, To, From, Subject, topic, Email_Content,
                Comments, Attachments);
        Items.add(item);//add item to linked list

    }

}
```

mainframe(where I set the data

```
loadItems(); //method used to load the data from the database
HomepagePanel.setData(controller.getItems());//sets data
```

Comment: yes I understood that but I'm not understanding why it is null since I set the data for it in my mainframe class.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the code that was not formatted properly. The code that is shown here only shows what is relevant to the table functionality of the table. I didn't enter in the code that lays out the homepagepanel because I thought it would be too much. Also loadItems() method is calling the controller's loaditem() method which is calling the method in my database class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
public class HomePagePanel { // note code conventios!
    ...
    public HomePagePanel() {
        ...
        emailModel = new EmailTableModel();
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<EmailTableModel>(emailModel);
        table = new JTable(emailModel);
        ...
    }
}
```

You don't call `emailModel.setData()` right before creating the table. It means your table model's data never is initialized and `dc` still being null at this point. Consequently when `getRowCount()` method is called during `JTable` creation it throws the NPE you're facing.

IMHO you should consider remove `setData()` method and add the items list to the `EmailTableModel` constructor instead, and better organize your code to avoid this kind of situation:

1. Do database call and get items list
2. Create a new table model
3. Create new `JTable`

---

### Edit

> *"Should i just call fireTableDataChanged when I insert or delete an
>   item?"*

No, you just need to provide methods to add/delete items to your table model and then notify [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html)s about such events. For instance:

```
public class EmailTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    ...
    public void addRow(Item item) {
        int rowIndex = dc.size();
        dc.add(item);
        fireTableRowsInserted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }
    ...
    public void deleteRow(Item item) {
        int rowIndex = dc.indexOf(item);
        if(rowIndex > -1) {
            dc.remove(item);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

See [AbstractTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html):

- [fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow,int
  lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29)
- [fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int
  lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: thanks, I did remove setdata and I did as you said. the only problem now is updating the table to show the updated result. I have to exit out of my program and run it again for this to happen. Should i just call fireTableDataChanged when I insert or delete an item?

Comment: or do I have to set the emailModel again each time I update the table?